# vector of POSIXct and sapply

Tags: r, posixct, sapply

What if you want to apply a function other than `format` to a list of POSIXct objects?  For instance, say I want to take a vector of times, truncate those times to the hour, and apply an arbitrary function to each one of those times.

```
> obs.times=as.POSIXct(c('2010-01-02 12:37:45','2010-01-02 08:45:45','2010-01-09 14:45:53'))
> obs.truncated=trunc(obs.times, units="hours")
> obs.truncated
[1] "2010-01-02 12:00:00 EST" "2010-01-02 08:00:00 EST"
[3] "2010-01-09 14:00:00 EST"
```

Now, I would expect the length of `obs.truncated` to be 3 but

```
> length(obs.truncated)
[1] 9
```

So you can see that trying to `apply` a function to this vector is not going to work.  The class of `obs.truncated` is

```
> class(obs.truncated)
[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXlt"
```

Any idea what is going on here?  `apply` and `length` appear to be taking the first element of the vector as its own list.

Comment: Don't know why this is happening to you: I ran your commands and got `length(obs.truncated)` == 3...but I get 9 from the following: `length(unclass(obs.truncated))`.

Comment: I am using:

R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14) 
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: Long story short: upgrade to R 2.11 or use something other than trunc, as Dirk says below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `length()` of such a POSIXlt used to be reported as nine, but that got recently corrected.

Also, when I do `trunc(obs.times)` the wrong thing happens -- `trunc()` operates only once on a string of three elements.  you do need `apply()` et al.

So here is an example of using `sapply()` with component-wise resetting:

```
> sapply(obs.times, function(.) {
+ p <- as.POSIXlt(.); 
+ p$min <- p$sec <- 0; 
+ format(p) })
[1] "2010-01-02 12:00:00" "2010-01-02 08:00:00" "2010-01-09 14:00:00"
>
```

Whereas

```
> trunc(obs.times, units="hours")
[1] "2010-01-02 12:00:00 CST" "2010-01-02 08:00:00 CST"
[3] "2010-01-09 14:00:00 CST"
> class(trunc(obs.times, units="hours"))
[1] "POSIXt"  "POSIXlt"
> length(trunc(obs.times, units="hours"))
[1] 1
>
```

Comment: The OP includes the `class` command in the question.  Also, when I call `trunc` it applies to the whole vector.  But you're right: I can replicate the 9 count using R 2.10.0, but it's corrected in my R 2.11.1 console.

Comment: Great, but I'm still confused by your second paragraph.  This is what I get: `base::trunc(obs.times, units="hours")` >> `[1] "2010-01-02 12:00:00 EST" "2010-01-02 08:00:00 EST" "2010-01-09 14:00:00 EST"` (same as in OP example).  I also looked at the `$sec` and `$min` slots and they are all zero.

Comment: I tossed that into the main post. The length() == 1 seems fishy. R 2.11.0.

Comment: I get `length(trunc(obs.times, units="hours"))` >> `3` in R 2.11.1 on Windoze.  How odd!

Comment: Might be a bug fixed between .0 and .1  !

Comment: Do you know if they have regression tests for things like this in base R?  I would have imagined as much, but I never looked into it...

Comment: Sure, there is a `make check` target. But you can't test all possible options and results for all possible functions...